# angular $routeProvider with html5

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a problem with `$routeProvider` when I use html5mode correctly.
when I access `/profile/: child` it will be fine, but when the page is refreshed, then on the page that will be errors. is there something wrong with my code below:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

var pathViews = function (file) {
    return 'http://localhost/mycompany/app/views/' + file;
};
var pathError = function (file) {
    return 'app/views/error/' + file;
};
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: pathViews('dashboard.html'),
        controller :'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: pathViews('dashboard.html'),
        controller :'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/profile/:child', {
        templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
            return pathViews($routeParams.child+'.html')},
                controller:'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/404', {
        templateUrl: pathError('404.html'),
        controller :'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/form-standard', {
        templateUrl: pathViews('form-standard.html'),
        controller :'MainCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/404'});});
```

and the index.html is:
`<div ng-view ></div>`

Comment: Could you explain what the error is and post it if there is any output in the console log?

Comment: I have no log at browser, browser just like not responding..

Comment: not responding as in keeps loading, or loading empty page, more details?

Comment: Could you make a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2)?

Comment: yerken- not blank page, I don't know keep loading or other, but not show loading icon at browser, like load page done but I can't click any things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal since when you refresh your page your web server tries to load the requested resource that doesn't exist on the server but instead is handled on the client side.

For example,if you deploy a "routeProvided" angularjs application on an Apache, you should edit your `.htaccess` ([source](https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag#comment-1431739045)):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

In plain english, you have to tell your web server to redirect every request to your main module entry point.

Comment: I have try to use .htaccess, it was. but not solving